# Regex Only one special character at a time from allowed special characters Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow 3 characters 1st Underscore (_) , 2nd hyphen (-) 3rd Dot (.)

but i want to put conditions that only one character is allowed at a time from all of them, and also only one time.

e.g
allowed usernames = abc.def , abc-def , abc_def
not allowed usernames = abc.de.f alert here(only one special character is allowed in a username)
not allowed usernames = abc.de-f , abc.de_f , ab-cd_ef

What should i do.

Comment: There are lots of resources for learning about regular expressions.  Give it a try yourself and come back and post some code when you have issues more specific than "how do I do it?"

Comment: So alpha-characters a hyphen, underscore, or dot, then more alpha characters? `^[a-zA-Z]+[-._][a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: @chris85 I am sorry i forgot to mention, letters and numbers both allowed

Comment: @AtifSheikh Okay so add `0-9` with the alpha character classes. Does that work?

Comment: @chris85 Yes i got and i did it but there is an issue with that, if i put one dot, it gives an error, but if i put more than one dot then it works. i am using this code:
        'if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-._][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(x)){
        document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "Only One - _ or . can be used in Usernames";
        return false;
        }'

Comment: @AtifSheikh Can you provide samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/^[a-z]*[-._]?[a-z]*$/`

```js
var tests = ['abc.def', 'abc-def', 'abc_def', 'abc.de.f','abc.de-f' , 'abc.de_f', 'ab-cd_ef'];
$.each(tests, function(a,b) {
  $('body').append('<div>' + b + ' = ' + regIt(b) + '</div>');
});

function regIt(str) {
  return /^[a-z]*[-._]?[a-z]*$/.test(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The dot doesn't need to be escaped in the character class. If you put `-` first it also doesn't need to be escaped. This also will allow for empty usernames.

Comment: @chris85 , thank you

Comment: @br3t it worked perfectly fine what i was looking for. i just used

if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(x))

Thanks br3t and chris85. Love you seniors :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-z]*([-._]?)(?:[a-z]|\1)*$
```

This regex will match letters until it reaches the end of the string. If it reaches a symbol (`-` `.` or `_`) it will store that symbol as group 1, and keep matching for letters or that same symbol until the end of the string.

The following are matching examples:

- an empty string
- `_something`
- `something-something`
- `foo_bar_baz`
- `foo.`

And here are some invalid strings:

- `my_file.txt`
- `alpha.bravo_charlie`
- `not-working_`

Comment: OP wants only one special character. `foo_bar_baz` is not allowed because there are 2 underscores.

Comment: @Toto Indeed, I misread. br3t's answer is the right one want then.